# How can I bill within an application

Tags: currency, billing, banking

I've been programming for years, and I've also done a few professional programming projects. I recently had a friend ask about creating an e-commerce site, but I had to turn her down because I had never worked on a web application that can bill. I also might need to write a subscription-based web service in the future. My question is, how do I even get started with billing? I've never found a guide about this, and I barely know how bank accounts work since I don't manage my own one (I have an excuse for this since I'm only 16).

I don't know if the answer is language dependent, but if it is the languages I'm interested in are Python, C/C++, and Java.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Experience with billing systems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573468/experience-with-billing-systems)

Comment: I think the goal is to do as little of the work yourself; you can integrate with e.g. http://www.PayPal.com (the http://www.pragprog.com ["friday" on PayPal and ruby](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/jfpaypal/payment-processing-with-paypal-and-ruby) was pretty good) or another service such as http://www.braintreepaymentsolutions.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of ways to go about setting up e-commerce sites;

If you don't have any experience whatsoever, and don't want to get into anything "complicated", i would suggest going with a customizable web "storefront" hosted by someone else, pre-integrated with credit card processing, etc. There are tons of options for these online. Just search google for "web storefront". Yahoo! even has such a service:

http://smallbusiness.yahoo.com/ecommerce/sellonline.php

Going beyond that, It's pretty easy to integrate with someone like PayPal. They have all sorts of options from the most basic (use a link to send someone to their site with query string parameters to let paypal know what the user wanted to buy):

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?&cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/home

Beyond that level, you will need to signup for a merchant account, or other similar sort of service, like the one offered by authorize.net (who I like):

http://www.authorize.net/

There are components you can buy for most major web development platforms like .NET, JSP, etc. Perfect example is dotnetcart. These components provide out-of-the-box, easy-to-setup integrations with major CC processing companies, as well as out-of-the-box shopping cart implementations:

http://www.dotnetcart.com/

Finally, most merchant services / payment gateways provide web services for direct integration.

PS.) Never ever ever store CC numbers ; )

Answer (score 2):

I would look at paypal's api to get started.  You might not want to stick with them but it is a good starting place to learn about dealing with credit card clearing houses and such.

[Here ya go.](https://www.x.com/index.jsp)

Answer (score 1):

You'll typically interface with a 3rd-party for doing banking transactions. One that I've work with in the past is Authorize.Net but there's plenty out there (PayPal is another fairly popular one with a decent API).

Basically, the best approach is to do *as little as possible* and let the 3rd party handle all the "hard" stuff (such as security, managing credit card details and so on).